# Puede alguien explicarme este error que significa en xamp o wamp

Tags: xampp, wamp

Sorry,
Please create C:\xampp\htdocs\swcol/cache.storage.localhost:5555/
and SET Mode 0777 or any Writable Permission!

Comment: que tiene que ver la etiqueta angular?

Comment: puedo enviar los archivos de configuracion que necesiten creo que mi problema especificamente esta con archivo htacces pero no se que pasaria si lo borrase o si lo eliminase el error es comun tanto en el wamp como en xamp

Comment: el sitio web que intento levantar esta concebido en angular

Comment: Basicamente que no existe la ruta o no tiene permisos de escritura.

Comment: estoy trbajando en windows puede decirme como creo dicha ruta o como le doy los permisos necesarios